# Accessing data from subclass within a proxy filter

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get data from a QGeoCoordinate within my own class NavaidsModel.

Here is the constructor of NavaidsModel :

```
class NavaidsModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

NavaidsModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QAbstractListModel(parent){
}
enum NavaidsRoles {
    PositionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1, 
    OACICodeRole,
    CountryCodeRole
};
```

Here is the filterAcceptsRow() of my proxyfilter NavaidsFilter :

```
bool NavaidsFilter::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QRegExp rx("ROBU");

    QAbstractItemModel *model = sourceModel();

        QHashIterator<int, QByteArray> it(sourceModel()->roleNames());
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            it.next();
            QModelIndex sourceIndex = model->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);

            //Here are the tests to get the data
            qDebug() <<"Data 257 :" << sourceIndex.data(257); //PositionRole
            qDebug() <<"Data 258 :" << sourceIndex.data(258); //OACICodeRole
            qDebug() <<"Data 259 :" << sourceIndex.data(259); //CountryCodeRole

            QString key = model->data(sourceIndex, it.key()).toString();
            if (key.contains(rx))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

And here are the qDebug() results :

```
index.row =  0 role =  257
Point :  "MM"   "ROBSO"   QGeoCoordinate(21.75, -107.12556, 0)
PositionRole  QGeoCoordinate(21.75, -107.12556, 0) 
Data 257 : QVariant(QGeoCoordinate, )

index.row =  0 role =  258
Point :  "MM"   "ROBSO"   QGeoCoordinate(21.75, -107.12556, 0)
OACICodeRole  "ROBSO" 
Data 258 : QVariant(QString, "ROBSO")


index.row =  0 role =  259
Point :  "MM"   "ROBSO"   QGeoCoordinate(21.75, -107.12556, 0)
CountryCodeRole  "MM" 
Data 259 : QVariant(QString, "MM")
```

OACICode an CountryCode are OK as we can see in the results.
But, for Data 257, I wish to get the values (lat = 21.75 ; lon =-107.12556 ; alt =0) to compare within a boundary limit, and at this time, I'm not able to obtain them in any way.

How can I achieved that ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I suspect this is simply a limitation of `qDebug` and `QVariant`.  When outputting a `QVariant` `qDebug` knows how to handle basic types such as `QString` etc., but not `QGeoCoordinate`.  Try replacing `sourceIndex.data(257)` with `sourceIndex.data(257).value<QGeoCoordinate>().toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the model I showed you in a previous question:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= mPoints.count())
        return QVariant();

    const NavaidsPoint &point = mPoints[index.row()];
    if (role == PositionRole)
        return QVariant::fromValue(point.position());
    else if (role == OACICodeRole)
        return point.oaciCode();
    else if (role == CountryCodeRole)
        return point.countryCode();
    return QVariant();
}
```

The `data()` method returns a `QVariant`, but there are some types that are not supported by default, to solve it use [`QVariant::fromValue()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue), so if you want to get the value you should use [`QVariant::value()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value) const as I show below.

```
#ifndef NAVAIDSFILTER_H
#define NAVAIDSFILTER_H

#include "navaidsmodel.h"

#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QRegularExpression>

#include <QDebug>

class NavaidsFilter : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
    NavaidsFilter(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QSortFilterProxyModel(parent){}
protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const{

        QRegularExpression rx("ROBU");

        QModelIndex ix = sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);
        QGeoCoordinate pos = ix.data(NavaidsModel::PositionRole).value<QGeoCoordinate>();
        QString code = ix.data(NavaidsModel::OACICodeRole).toString();
        QString country = ix.data(NavaidsModel::CountryCodeRole).toString();

        qDebug()<<pos<<code<<country;

        if(code.contains(rx)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

#endif // NAVAIDSFILTER_H
```

**Note:**

- It is not advisable to use the numbers associated with the roles, it is preferable to use the values of the enum, since they make your code more readable.
- Use `QRegularExpression` instead of `QRegExp` since this class will be eliminated in a short time.

Comment: Great, great. I thank you very much you two. Eyllanesc, I progress on the bases you gave me earlier and yes, data() stay without any change. And you help me too on the role. I thought wrongly that the way to get it was something like ix::PositionRole without success, of course. Include of navaidsmodel.h make sense to get the role of the source.